# How to Roll Back changes in ADO main Repo to a specific PR merge?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm facing a problem in the current Project.
There was a Merge happened yesterday with some unwanted code being pushed into main( close to 4K changes). I've tried to revert the changes from PR request, but throws an error asking me to do this manually. The exact Error is

`"Encountered conflicts when reverting commit "***670". This operation needs to be performed locally.`

I need to roll back to the PR merge before this commit/Merge. Please help me achieve it.
The source branch gets deleted whenever it's merged and its squash merge.

There was another merge just before this Merge and want to roll back to that PR Merge. Is it possible ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Edward Thomson

Comment: Do you wish to `revert` the bad merge, which means create a new commit (and possibly a new PR) which undoes the changes of the bad merge, or, do you wish to `reset` back to before the bad merge and make it appear as if the bad merge, **as well as every PR completed to that branch after the bad merge**, never happened? Note one disadvantage of resetting is that you will lose all commits after the bad merge, and you will have to force push the branch, which could potentially mess up other users of the repo.

Comment: I've tried reverting the bad merge, but there is an error ""Encountered conflicts when reverting commit "***670". This operation needs to be performed locally."

So at this point I wish to go  with the reset back to before the bad merge.
After the bad merge, there was only one merge happened and I was able to revert it back successfully, hoping the after this merge, the bad merge would also revert( by clicking revert on the PR), but unfortunately there was this above error when I try to revert from bad merge. 
So there are no more merges after the bad merge now, it's only this bad merge nw

Comment: When reverting multiple merges, you should revert them in reverse order that they occurred, and it sounds like you did this. Based on what you described I can't think of any reason why it would get conflicts. But if you wish to reset, it's simply `git switch <branch-name>` and then `git reset --hard <commit-id-you-wish-to-point-to>` and then `git push --force-with-lease`. Note that force pushing a shared branch is extremely frowned upon and may potentially mess up other collaborators on the repo. (Use at your own risk!)

Comment: Side note, AzDO retains all history of every push, so even if you force push a shared branch, if you change your mind later, you can still get it back. (As long as you are accessing the repo where the force push occurred. This is not true if you clone the new version and push to a new repo.)